# How to identify whether a layout manager has been used?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I'm trying to figure out whether a given GUI is created using a layout manager in Java or not. If there is an import statement as follows does that mean the GUI was generated using a layout manager?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interface extends WindowAdapter {

     JFrame f;

     Interface() { 
      int a=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,"Would you like to view statistics?");  
      if(a==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
       String displayText = "The amount of times it stalled " + String.valueOf(FollowTheLight.stalls) + "\n";
       displayText += "Total travel time: " + String.valueOf(FollowTheLight.totaltime) + "\n";
       displayText += "Number of stops: " + String.valueOf(FollowTheLight.invfwd);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayText);
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
      }

     }
}
```

Is this an accurate method? Are there any other methods?

Comment: That tells you nothing.  A better approach is to search the code for `setLayout(null)`.  If you don’t find that, then every container is using a layout manager.

Comment: The import statements doesn't mean that a layout manager was used. Everyone could at this line to a `.java` file.

Comment: Look for `setLayout` commands. Try changing the default font size and running the program

Comment: @VGR Also `new JPanel(null)` (for 'not find')..

Comment: @VGR I've edited the question to include more sample code. Just to confirm, so the above UI is generated using a layout manager?

Comment: @SriniShine The posted code has nothing related to layout manager... What are you talking about?

Comment: JOptionPane uses its own private layout manager.  A JFrame would use a layout manager, but `f` is null (which means the code will generate a NullPointerException when it reaches f.setDefaultCloseOperation).